# Resize fabricjs Canvas elements in smaller div

Tags: html, angular, fabricjs

I am trying to redraw fabricjs canvas elements into a div of smaller size.
I tried resizing using ngstyle but didn't work. I am not sure if am calculating scaling in the wright way.

```
 <div 
  *ngFor="let label of layout.labels" 
  [ngStyle]="
        { 'top.px' : ((label.top - rect.top) / label.scaleY),
          'left.px' : (label.left - rect.left) / label.scaleX,
          'width.px' :  (label.width) / label.scaleX,
          'max-width.px': 200,
          'max-height.px': 200,
          'height.px' : (label.height / label.scaleY),
          'position':'relative',
          'background-color': 'yellow', 
          'text-align': label.textAlign
        }">
  </div>
```

Comment: You can't resize objects using css.

Comment: I resolved it by using fittext package. thanks.